# msyql version 8.0 installation Ubuntu but installing msyql 5.7

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am trying to install mysql8.0 version

Environment - Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Running below command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

But below message is coming

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server
```

It is installing mysql5.7 but i would like to install mysql8.0

Please assist on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade to MySQL 8.0?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1122608). Besides that, after updating to 20.04 LTS or 22.04 LTS, MySQL 8.0 can be installed from `apt-get` without additional steps

Comment: I have tried with above link but seems not worked...

Comment: Now I am upgrading 20 ubuntu